# Reduce Inequality

Tags: equation-solving

How can I reduce the inequality in terms of modulus of alpha.

```
Reduce[Abs[-((-1 + Sqrt[ 1 + 4 α] + α (-3 + Sqrt[1 + 4 α]) + 
          Sqrt[ 2 - 2 Sqrt[1 + 4 α] +  2 α (-2 +  4 Sqrt[1 + 4 α] + 
          α (-11 + 2 α + Sqrt[ 1 + 4 α]))])/(2 (-1 - 2 α + Sqrt[1 + 4 α])))] < 1]
```

Comment: Please provide your expression as *Mathematica* code. What have you tried already?

Comment: This is your fourth question and you never posted a single line in the Mathematica language. Please stop posting just TeX and formulas.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Reals

```
f[α_]:= -((-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 α] + α (-3 + Sqrt[1 + 4 α]) + 
           Sqrt[2 - 2 Sqrt[1 + 4 α] + 2 α (-2 + 4 Sqrt[1 + 4 α] + α (-11 + 2 α + 
           Sqrt[1 + 4 α]))])/(2 (-1 - 2 α +  Sqrt[1 + 4 α])))
Reduce[-1 < f[α] < 1, α]

(* Root[-4 + 20 #1 - 12 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2] <= α < 2 *)
```

For Complexes (still working on it)

```
RegionPlot[Abs@f[x + I y] < 1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What about for Complex case?

Comment: Root[-4 + 20 #1 - 12 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2] <= α < 2    What is this? I do not understand the equation with # symbo. Can you please tell me what is the equation of which Roots should be less than equal to 2 alpha.

Comment: @SkSarifHassan You could check the docs for `Root[ ]` or search for questions in this site involving about it. In any case, if feel too lazy to do that try `Root[-4 + 20 #1 - 12 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2]  //N`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not lazy really. I do not know these.

Comment: @SkSarifHassan `ToRadicals` (sometimes combined with `ComplexExpand`) may also make `Root` values (at least simpler ones with closed form) more understandable. For instance, try `Root[-4 + 20 #1 - 12 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 2] // ToRadicals // ComplexExpand`. This may be good for the end user; if you plan to feed these results back to Mathematica, don't perform such transitions for no apparent reasons. Mma likes `Root`s.