# How to reduce/simplify an inequality involving Abs[]?

Tags: inequalities

Can *Mathematica* reduce this inequality into a domain of `z`, where {`z`, `r1`, `r2`} are all complex?

```
Reduce[Abs[z^2 - r1] > Abs[z^3 - r2], z]
```

The line never returns a result.  I also tried just calculating the boundary:

```
Simplify[Abs[z^2 - r1] == Abs[z^3 - r2]]
```

But that never returns a result either.  I've tried a few other methods that all just crashed or failed.  I found a related [Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87657/reduce-inequality) and another related [Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92503/reduction-of-an-inequality-in-mathbbc) but I couldn't figure out how to apply those partial solutions to this problem.

BTW, I realize `Solve[]` and `Reduce[]` don't cope with `Abs[]`.  Even this simpler command give a poor result:

```
Simplify[Abs[z^2] == Abs[z^3]];

(* Abs[z]^2 == Abs[z] *)
```

And just to be clear, I don't just need the answer to the inequality, I need to know how to make *Mathematica* do it.

Comment: You should tell `Reduce` you're working over the reals: `Reduce[Abs[z^2 - r1] > Abs[z^3 - r2], z, Reals]`.

Comment: @ChipHurst  I'm not.  I'll add clarification that the variables are complex.

Comment: How come my `tick` marks in the title aren't being turned into nice `Font`?

Comment: Titles entry fields don't support all the editing features as the editor pane that accepts the main body of a question. This is a quick of SE that has to be lived with.

Comment: What do you think `Simplify[Abs[z^2] == Abs[z^3]]` should return? Keep in mind `z` is considered complex unless otherwise stated.

Comment: @ChipHurst  It should return {Abs[z]==1, z==0}.

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify all of the variables you want to reduce over:

```
In[1]:= Reduce[Abs[z^2 - r1] > Abs[z^3 - r2], {z, r1, r2}, Complexes]
Out[1]= (* a huge pile of Im, Re and Sqrt omitted *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about adding `Complexes`, but yikes that huge pile result is not a good result.  I don't think it should be necessary to explicitly separate Im[z] and Re[z] in the result.