# Inequality involving Abs[]

Tags: equation-solving

Mathematica fails to do anything with

```
Reduce[Abs[x-3]<4, Reals]
(* Reduce[Abs[x-3]<4, Reals] *)
```

[This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99397/790) contends that explicitly naming the variables to be reduced will solve the problem, and indeed

```
Reduce[Abs[x-3]<4, x, Reals]
(* -1 < x < 7 *)
```

But why is this the case? If either the absolute value is removed, or the `<` is changed to `=`, it is not necessary to provide the variable name.

Comment: you can do `Reduce[RealAbs[x - 3] < 4]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some back and forth with WRI, here is the answer: the domain restriction in `Reduce[]` applies to the specified variables and functions involving those variables. Since no variables are specified in my first example, the domain restriction effectively does nothing. That also explains why using `{}` does not solve the problem.

EDIT: After reading @Michael's comment below, I had more interactions with Wolfram support, and I am still somewhat confused. From WRI:

---

From Reduce documentation:

"Algebraic variables in expr free of the Subscript[x, i] and of each other are treated as independent parameters."

Since no Subscript[x, i] are specified, Reduce solves for the algebraic-level variables that are free of other algebraic-level variables.

```
In[1]:= Reduce`FreeVariables[x^2<4, "Algebraic"]
Out[1]= {x}

In[2]:= Reduce`FreeVariables[Abs[x-3]<4 && x\[Element]Reals, "Algebraic"]
Out[2]= {x}

In[3]:= Reduce`FreeVariables[Abs[x-3]<4, "Algebraic"]
Out[3]= {Abs[-3 + x]}

In[4]:= Reduce`FreeVariables[Re[x] > 0, "Algebraic"]
Out[4]= {Re[x]}
```

I guess the point is that `x` appears "algebraically" only in the first example; in the other examples it is the `Abs` or `Re` expression that is the "algebraic-level" variable.

This is still pretty unclear to me at a conceptual level (although I now know how to get the results I want), but I'm not sure what further questions to ask to clarify the situation. BTW, ``` Reduce``FreeVariables ``` is not documented.

Comment: That was my first thought, which I put in a comment, but I deleted the comment after finding it was contradicted in the docs, the relevant parts of which I quote in my answer. Note that the `Subscript[x, i]` refer to the specified variables. The identification and treatment of the parameters seems explicit, deliberate and clear, which makes me think the techie that helped you didn't look thoroughly into the matter. It's happened to me before. Or the docs are wrong, but, as I said, the docs seem intentionally to make the point.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Just tagging you so you see the edit to the answer. I'd appreciate any further insights.

Comment: I think (guess) what they are saying is that `Reduce[expr, vars, dom]` is equivalent to something like ``Reduce[expr, 
 Union[Reduce`FreeVariables[{expr, {vars}}, "Algebraic"], 
  Flatten@{vars}],  dom]``, where `vars` and `dom` may be omitted. `Union` is not quite right because the order of `vars` matters and the additional free variables ("parameters") are treated as though order does not matter, at least not in the same way (another guess). It seems the docs are incomplete, which is not that unusual unfortunately. They tend to leave out things most users don't need to know.

Comment: If you haven't seen it, you might be interested in [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212270/what-does-reducefreevariables-really-do-and-can-we-rely-on-it)

Comment: @MichaelE2 What a rat's nest. I thought I was just asking a simple question...

Comment: @MichaelE2 BTW, your proposed equivalence above doesn't seem to quite work. Compare `Reduce[x y<4,{x},Reals]`, `Reduce[x y<4,{y},Reals]`, `Reduce[x y<4,{x,y},Reals]` with your formulation with `vars={x}`.

Comment: I know it's not quite right. That's what I meant by the 2nd half of the comment. `Union` sorts the variables, which messes up the order; the equivalent to `Reduce[x y < 4, {x}, Reals]` is `Reduce[x y < 4, {y, x}, Reals]`. The parameters should precede the variables. But even this is not completely correct. For instance `Reduce[x^2 + w y^2 < z]` is not identical to `Reduce[x^2 + w y^2 < z, vars]` for `vars` being `{w, x, y, z}` in any order.

Comment: Hi @rogerl, I am the author of the question Michael linked to.  I am still utterly puzzled by ``Reduce`FreeVariables``.  Something that I find disconcerting is that in a fresh kernel defining ``Reduce`FreeVariables[args__] := Null /; Print[{"FreeVar: ", args}]``, and then running something like `Reduce[Abs[x-3]<4, x, Reals]` reveals that `Reduce` doesn't even call `Reduce``FreeVariables``... so I don't know how WRI's response actually helps here.

Comment: @QuantumDot So I'm pretty much out of my depth here as regards MMA knowledge. But if you want to follow up with WRI, my case number is CASE:4368640. I'd love to hear what the result is.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect `Reduce` treats the second argument as a variable. For instance:

```
Reduce[2 Reals == 1, Reals]
(* Reals == 1/2 *)
```

So I'm not sure there's anything wrong with

```
Reduce[Abs[x-3] < 4, Reals]
(* Reduce[Abs[x-3] < 4, Reals] *)
```

However, from the docs ("Details"):

> `Reduce[expr,vars,dom]` restricts all variables and parameters to belong to the domain `dom`.
>   ...
>   Algebraic variables in `expr` free of the `Subscript[x, i]` and of each other are treated as independent parameters.

I think this means that in `Reduce[Abs[x-3]<4, {}, Reals]`, the `x` is not treated as a variable (to be solved for) but as a parameter, assumed to be real. Yet it still does not solve the inequality:

```
Reduce[Abs[x-3]<4, {}, Reals]
(* Abs[x-3]<4 *)
```

If you put the constraint in directly, you get the sought-after result:

```
Reduce[Abs[x - 3] < 4 && x \[Element] Reals, {}, Reals]
(* 1 < x < 7 *)
```

I would expect to get the same thing for `Reduce[Abs[x-3]<4, {}, Reals]`, since `x \[Element] Reals` is supposed to be assumed.

It may be a bug and should be reported to WRI.  See if they have an explanation.