# Obtaining non numerical elements from list containing equations

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose we have the following list:

`list= {a,3b + c - d,x1 - 4y,g + l,x2 + z}`

Is there a way to obtain a list of the non-numerical elements present here?

The output should be a list

`{a,b,c,d,x1,y,g,l,x2,z}`

Comment: `Variables[Level[list, {-1}]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @bmf has stated, the comments on this question suggesting the use of [Variables](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html) should be turned into an answer.

I have collated the comments (one of them my  own), and marked this answer 'Community Wiki': feel free to edit.

**Variables**

```
list={a,3b + c - d,x1 - 4y,g + l,x2 + z}
Variables@list

(* {a, b, c, d, g, l, x1, x2, y, z} *)
```

@Bob Hanlon has suggest the following neat modification:

```
Variables[Level[list, {-1}]]
```

(I now see that this was [also suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61143/106) by @Basheer Algohi in 2004)

**`` Reduce`FreeVariables ``**

In addition, both [J. M.'s persistent exhaustion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m-s-persistent-exhaustion) (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135539/106)), and [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/194329/106#comment505977_194329) (and others), have drawn attention to the (apparently) undocumented function `` Reduce`FreeVariables ``:

```
Reduce`FreeVariables@list

(* {a, b, c, d, g, l, x1, x2, y, z} *)
```

Both [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) and [rogerl](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/790/rogerl) have posted in-depth answers (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212325/106) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212287/106) on `` Reduce`FreeVariables ``, and point out (among other things) that this function can take an optional second argument.

Compare

```
Reduce`FreeVariables[x + Log[y]]
Reduce`FreeVariables[x + Log[y],"Algebraic"]

(* {x, y} *)
(* {x, Log[y]} *)
```

**`` Integrate`getAllVariables ``**

Another undocumented function, which [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) has suggested in an [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/194329/106) to another question, is `` Integrate`getAllVariables `` (and using his example):

```
Integrate`getAllVariables[Cos[t x] E^y, {}]

((*  {t, x, y}  *)
```

**Cross-References**

1. [Extracting variables from an expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21257/106)
2. [Get all variables in an expression with Variables[] [duplicate]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61131/106)
3. [What does Reduce`FreeVariables really do? And can we rely on it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/212270/106)

Comment: (+1) Many thanks for doing that. I honestly think that these approaches are the best and most straightforward and if it were up to me, I would accept one of those as the proper answer to the question. The other alternatives are fun, educational, etc etc :-)

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, the comments by @Bob Hanlon and @user1066 are the best approaches. Perhaps turn the comments into answers(?)

First suggestion

```
Reduce`FreeVariables[list]
```

Second suggestion

```
Integrate`getAllVariables[list, {}]
```

The above return

> [image: list]

Another way

```
Cases[list, _Symbol, Infinity]
```

Yet another one

```
Cases[list, Except[_?NumericQ, _Symbol], Infinity]
```

The above give

> [image: list2]

Edit 1: with the use of [**`Union`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html) you can arrange the list to be exactly the same as in the first two cases. So, the above can become

```
Union@Cases[list, _Symbol, Infinity]
```

and

```
Union@Cases[list, Except[_?NumericQ, _Symbol], Infinity]
```

which yield

> [image: list]

Edit 2: we can use the very impressive code developed by [**`Daniel Lichtblau`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846644/utility-to-extract-variables-from-an-expression/5849071#5849071) on stackoverflow.

```
Union@getAllVariables[list]
```

returns

> [image: list]

Answer (score 6):

Only a little shorter than Giovanni's:
Edit: (But not as shot as bmf, user1066, and Bob Hanlon)

```
Select[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Apply[List, list, Infinity], ! NumberQ[#] &]
```

`{a, b, c, d, x1, y, g, l, x2, z}`

It replaces the heads at all levels with `List` then Flatten all the lists and then selects the non-numbers.

Answer (score 4):

I have come up with an answer that works.

```
list = {a, 3 b + c - d, x1 - 4 y, g + l, x2 + z}

list = Flatten[StringSplit[ToString[#] & /@ Flatten[list],{"-", "+", " "}]]

elements =  DeleteCases[Cases[ToExpression[#] & /@ list, _?(! NumberQ[#] &)], Null]
```

The output is the following, which is what we wanted:

```
{a, 3 b + c - d, x1 - 4 y, g + l, x2 + z}

{"a", "3", "b", "", "", "c", "", "", "d", "x1", "", "", "4", "y", \
"g", "", "", "l", "x2", "", "", "z"}

{a, b, c, d, x1, y, g, l, x2, z}
```